# Universal enveloping algebra of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$

Tags: lie-algebras, universal-algebra

I'm studying the existence and the uniqueness of the universal enveloping algebra of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ but i don't understand why $\mathfrak{U(g)}$ is generated by $i(\mathfrak{g})$, where $i$ is the following morphism: $$i: \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{U}_{L}.$$

Is there anyone who can help me to understand?

Comment: We have that $\mathcal U(\mathcal g)$ is constructed as a quotient of the tensor algebra $T(\mathcal g)$, which is by definition the free associative algebra generated by $\mathcal g$.  Taking a quotient doesn't stop the image from being a generating set.

Comment: Additionally, if $\iota(\mathcal g)$ did not generate, then you could look at the subalgebra it did generate, and see that the subalgebra would still satisfy the universal property.